# showing only exception type and its reason not the whole stack-trace when an exception occurs but into log file

Tags: java, exception, logging, error-handling, struts2

I have a problem,I dont want show full stack-trace when an exception occurs but only the exception type. suppose

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'null' for key 3
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
```

Here I only want to write the exception type and reason for exception into my log file like

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'null' for key 3
```

So How to achieve this,I am using java,struts2 and hibernate3.
Note: Please no logging frameworks suggestions,Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `ex.getMessage()` which returns the detail message string of the exception.

The `Throwable` class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in the Java language. So, You will find more details on Javadoc here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html